# FileResult returning corrupt file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, fileresult

I'm creating a simple controller action in ASP.NET MVC 2 (under the .NET 4.0 framework) which will resize files.

I've got a controller like this (I've cut it down a bit):

```
public ActionResult GetFile(int fileId, string fileSource) {
    FileInfo file = repo.FindFileById(fileId);

    //do some resizing

    string mimeType = string.Empty;
    switch(file.Extension) {
        case ".jpg":
            mimeType = "image/jpg";
            break;
        //some more stuff
        default:
            mimeType = "text/png";
            break;
    }

    return File(file.FullName, mimeType);
}
```

On the file system it saves fine, I can view the resized file, but in the browser the file doesn't render.

I've used Charles to inspect the response and it comes back with a HTTP Status of 200, but the Image isn't visible.

If I try and save the image and view it Windows picture viewer says that it's corrupt.

I've also tried with ZIP (sans resizing ;)) and it returns a corrupt ZIP file.

I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong but I can't for the life of me spot it.

**Edit**

I've tested in both Cassini and IIS 7.5 (Windows 7) and recieve the problem in both instances.

Comment: I'm not saying this explains your issue, but as a side comment, shouldn't your default be "text/html"?

Comment: Untested stab in the dark, try using a FileResult instead of an ActionResult?

Comment: Could you provide a stripped down version of your image resizing code that illustrates the problem as well as a sample image that we could use to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - I'm 100% sure it's not the resizing code. As stated I tested with sending a ZIP (with the correct ZIP mime type) and the same problem occurs

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to proceed by elimination. Start with a simple action and a working jpeg image:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return File("test.jpg", "image/jpeg");
}
```

If this doesn't work then you might be having some other problem (you might also try clearing the browser cache). If it works replace the `test.jpg` by the one you have but before resizing, etc, until you find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem is caused by a Http Compression module which is running on the site, it's trying to transform the image response, corrupting the image.

Answer (score 0):

The correct mime type for a jpeg is image/jpeg, not image/jpg. This will cause issues.

You should also post your resizing code as this is likely the cause of your corruption. What happens if you just read the fine and write it back out?

Answer (score 0):

Try using FileResult instead of ActionResult

Comment: The OP has already posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3593586/3982001), explaining what the problem was.